Can I add a region without writing Twig myself?
I have a 10.3.1 core with a sub theme in which I customize JavaScript and CSS but not Twig, so can I add a region without writing Twig myself?
This isn't urgent so if it isn't possible with Drupal 10, should the upcoming Drupal 11 include a way to do that?

Maybe a module like this https://www.drupal.org/project/blockgroup, but honestly is so easy to create a region with code. Add region to your theme's info.yml and then add it to your page.html.twig

@Ronnie I have done what you describe several times and can't stand the repetitiveness in adding a reference to the new region both in info.yml and page.html.twig and also creating a softlink for page.html.twig. I am looking for something with less steps.

You just do it once, how often are you adding new regions? It takes <30 seconds to add a new region. If you're doing css you must surely be use to repetitiveness

The list of regions supported by a theme are listed in its .info.yml file, but they are rendered in its page.html.twig file. Without editing the latter file, it is not possible to render new regions.

In Drupal, a region is declared in the theme .info (or .info.yml) file, but it is not rendered if the page.tpl.php (Drupal 7) or the page.html.twig (Drupal 8+) template file does not render the new region.
There isn't a way to tell Drupal This is a new region; rendered it in a default position. and that is not going to change in Drupal 11.
The alternatives are creating one or more blocks, as blocks essentially add content to a region, or implementing hook_page_top() or hook_page_bottom(). The latter just alter two of the available theme regions.
If then the changes are very limited in scope, hook_preprocess_HOOK() is an alternative, but only when changing the content of the $variable parameter passed to the hook has the desired effect.
Creating a block allows to make more changes, but as comments said, I would rather add a new region and render it by changing the page.html.twig template file.
A sub-theme is usually created because there are differences with the parent theme, and that also includes what specific template files render. It does not seem to have much sense, to create a sub-theme, but avoid changing any template file.
